# OpenShift 504 gateway timeout

Tags: openshift-online-2

I'm testing OpenShift Free tier package and encountered 504 gateway timeout. I have installed WordPress on 2 small gears and MySQL on another small gear. The error was encountered when I run WordPress StatPress plugin in the admin dashboard. My WordPress site is working fine. I have no problem with this plugin on my VPS hosting account.